# Is probably going to or is going to probably

Tags: grammaticality, vocabulary

Are both of those sentences grammatically correct?

> I am going to ***probably*** leave my children with a babysitter until I get employment.

Or

> I am ***probably*** going to leave my children with a babysitter until I get employment.

I know the second is correct, but is the first also correct?

I have come across a sentence which is very similar to this sentence in structure:

> Some experts think unemployment is to likey go on rising this year.

Comment: The first is not idiomatic, although you might split an infinitive with an adverb like 'kindly'. Anyway, where will you leave the children *after* you get employment?

Comment: "to likely go".... "[to boldly go](https://www.merriam-webster.com/wordplay/to-boldly-split-infinitives)"... *Some experts think unemployment is likely to go on rising this year.*

Comment: Whether or not it's strictly permitted by the rules of grammar, the first sentence with that usage of "probably" sounds clumsy and not-quite-right, as if they were a foreign speaker,   or perhaps choosing to saying it in a funny way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are both technically acceptable, but the second is best. The first creates a split infinitive---it breaks up "to leave." You can, on occasion, get away with doing that when a phrase has become so widely accepted in the culture as to stand on its own, but as a rule, you should avoid doing so. Purely grammatically, it isn't correct in the strictest sense---though everyone would understand what you meant either way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).